# Erro em uma das funções do programa que calcula um fatorial

Tags: c

Não consigo arrumar o erro da última função "fatorial2", que no caso seria o fatorial da parte de baixo desse calculo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Programa:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


double fatorial(int n);
double fatorial2(int x, int y);

int main()
{
    int n;
    int k;
    double A;

    printf("Digite os valores de N e K: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &k);


    A = (float)fatorial(n) / fatorial2(n, k);

    printf("Fatorial = %.0lf", A);

    getch();
    return 0;
}


double fatorial(int n)
{

    double cima;

    if ( n <= 1 )

        return (1);
    else
    {

        cima = n * fatorial(n - 1);
        return (cima);
    }
}
double fatorial2(int x, int y)
{

    double baixo;

    if ( (x <= 1) && (y <= 1))
        return (1);
    else
    {

        baixo = (x - y) * fatorial2((x - y) - 1);
        return (baixo);
    }
}
```

Comment: E qual erro você está tendo?

Comment: A assinatura da função na questão pede para retornar `int` não `double`. Aproveito e reforço a pergunta do @prmottajr , qual o erro? O que está acontecendo ou deixando de acontecer?

Comment: a função que citei esta dando erro, e exibindo a seguinte mensagem "Pouco argumento para a função 'fatorial2'"

Comment: Não consigo perceber o porque de ter implementado duas funções de fatorial quando pode simplesmente utilizar uma, fazendo `A = (float)fatorial(n) / fatorial(n - k);`

Comment: Nada melhor que experimentar mesmo. Pegue no seu código e remova todas as referências para o `fatorial2`, e deixe apenas essa linha como eu indiquei para o calculo do `A`, e veja se não é o resultado que está a procura. Lembre-se que `fatorial(n-k)` o parametro é 1 na mesma, que é a subtração entre 2 valores. Se `n` for `10` e `k` for `4` irá equivaler a fazer `fatorial(6)`

Comment: caramba, deu certo... kkkkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testa desse jeito aqui:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


double fatorial(int n);
double fatorial2(int x, int y);

int main()
{
  int n;
  int k;
  double A;

  printf("Digite o valor de N: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("\nDigite o valor de K: ");
  scanf("%d", &k);


  A = (float)fatorial(n) / fatorial2(n, k);

  printf("\nFatorial = %.0lf", A);

  getch();
  return 0;
}


double fatorial(int n)
{

   double cima;

   if ( n <= 1 )

     return (1);
   else
   {
     cima = n * fatorial(n - 1);
     return (cima);
   }
}

double fatorial2(int x, int y)
{

   double baixo;

   if ( (x <= 1) && (y <= 1))
      return (1);
   else
   {
      baixo = (x - y) * (fatorial((x-y)-1));
      return (baixo);
   }
}
```

Comment: Se você explicasse o que fizera no código, seria uma resposta válida. Aproveitando, na questão se pede que a função `fatorial` retornando inteiro

Comment: função fatorial calcula o fatorial de n (a parte de cima) e fatorial2 calcula a parte de baixo (n-k)!, dps, uso as duas funções para a formula n!/(n-k)!, ai fica A que é o resultado, e (float) fatorial (n)/ fatorial2(n,k) para a formula citada anteriormente....